# Do Hindus believe that Idols make a person spiritually closer to God?

Tags: worship, gods, idols

Is the idol target of worship or is God the target? Is the idol used only to get nearer to God? If yes how can an idol bring us nearer to God?

Comment: this question specifically asks do hindus believe that Idols make a person closer to God?

Comment: I think that will be opinion based and hence it will be off topic, if you want to know why we target idols to worship god, than the duplicate question will answer your question :)

Comment: I am asking about standard belief hence it cant be offtopic

Comment: Does looking at a photograph of your loved ones inspire finer feeling in you? Does it make you remember them? This is a very simplistic analogy but sufficient for now. Idol worship has significance and powerful energies associated with it but it is not necessary to go into their detail for this question.

Answer (score 3):

No, idols are just a mean to grow inner faith, devotion and attachment to God. So the Garuda Puran states:

> *na kāśṭhe vidyate devo na śilāyam na mrutsuca
>
>   bhāve hi vasate devastasmādbhāvo hi kāraṇam* [GP - 2.28.11]
>
> **Meaning**
>   Deva (god) is neither present in the wood nor in the stone, nor in the soil (i.e. idols made of these things). He resides only in the emotion or feelings (*bhava*), hence *bhava* (devotion / emotion) is the only reason.

But it's difficult for an embodied being with a form to concentrate and worship the formless:

> For those whose minds are attached to the unmanifested, impersonal
>   feature of the Supreme, advancement is very troublesome. To make
>   progress in that discipline is always difﬁcult for those who are
>   embodied. [BG - 12.5]

Hence, in Hinduism there is also the provision for worshiping idols.

Comment: This is what means getting closer to god i.e "grow inner faith, devotion and attachment to God."